# Setting child properties with Object.assign in parent

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
export class A {
    parent?: string;

    constructor(attrs: object = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, attrs);
    }
}

export class B extends A {
    public child?: string;
}

console.log(new B({parent: "1", child: "2"}));
// Results in:
// Object {parent: "1", child: undefined}
```

The `Object.assign` in the parent class doesn't set any of the attributes in the child class. I don't want to have to specify a constructor for every child class that calls super and another `Object.assign`.

Is there some way to assign all properties on a child class using a single method in the parent class, *without having to specify each property explicity*?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Ctrl+Enter and check the console, it looks fine: https://typescript-play.js.org/?target=2#code/AQYwNghgzlwILAN4ChhuABwgJwKYDsAXAfgC5gpDsBLfAcwG5lV0QB7fS7AVxELewAKCISpRybAEYArXH2ABeJAF8AlEhbp0AeRlzCAOmhRqdfIMIALalAA0wEWNVMty5G+ThjwAELBcAB6EBAAmsAgoWhjckmDUIKDWYCFkFFS0jO7M7JxsYLgGYGx0gvi4AO6+gohYeETkAEQAjA32IEkhjQBMDWrOyEA

Comment: I can't seem to produce your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/9h27nqLo. Note that your method is not bullet-proof though: you can still create a new `child` member in the `A` class despite it not being declared.

Comment: Hmm, I'll flip some compiler flags to see if I see any changes.

Comment: Maybe you are explicitly initializing the field with `undefined `? Inituslizers run after the base class constructor

Comment: I just did `create-react-app` again, added typescript with `npm install typescript`, added the same `tsconfig.json`, added the two classes to a `test.ts` and the `console.log` to the `index.js`, and I get the same issue again. My guess for now is either: 1) the create-react-app config has something I don't know about, 2) my `tsconfig` has some weird setting.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir You were right. The constructor in the super class is called, it sets the attributes correctly; however, after that the values are automatically put back to `undefined`. I guess for now I'll just have to always define a constructor in the child classes.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a difference between running the code above in Node and in the React app.
[image: screenshot from react]

This is the compiled code which runs in Node (works fine):

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.A = void 0;
class A {
    constructor(attrs = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, attrs);
    }
}
exports.A = A;
class B extends A {
}
console.log(new B({ parent: "1", child: "2" }));
```

And here's the code from webpack that runs in the browser (not working as expected).

```
"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "A", function() { return A; });
class A {
  constructor(attrs = {}) {
    this.parent = void 0;
    Object.assign(this, attrs);
  }

}

class B extends A {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.child = void 0;
  }

}

console.log(new B({
  parent: "1",
  child: "2"
}));
```

I also don't know why webpack is doing this

```
this.child = void 0;
```

Would be nice to know. Anybody?

Comment: `void 0` is the shortest expression that produces `undefined` value - it's used for compatibilty with older JavaScript engines that still allow to declar a variable named `undefined`.

Comment: It is likely not webpack but babel or typescript that "transpiles" your code so it can be compatible with engies that does support features like class properties. `void 0` is used as `parent` and `child` where defined without a value, thus the value is set to `undefined`.